# How can I get amount of "free" memory in Unity3d on iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I have a problem: if I try to create a screenshot with [Texture2D.ReadPixels](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html), the game crashes on some devices (most notably, iPod 4G). Supposedly, it happens because of low memory. Before creating screenshot, I want to detect, if I can allocate the required amount of memory safely, and show the warning to the player if I suppose I will crash.

However, it seems that resources like textures are managed outside of Mono VM. System.GC.GetTotalMemory returns 9mb, when I have atlases as big as 16mb. So, it seems that I have to write a plugin for that.

(There was a section describing that I didn't receive low memory warnings, but it seems that I was mistaken about it, and on Objective-C level, the warnings are successfully raised).

How can I get the amount of "free" memory that I can allocate without crashing? May be there's some other way to achieve the functionality I want?

Comment: Have you tried Application.CaptureScreenshot? http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html

Comment: I need to show this screenshot to the user and offer him to send to facebook or other places in the dialog, and async CaptureScreenshot doesn't suit this usecase.

Comment: The Prime31 etcetera plugin has some native code that can resize and load textures from the file system `resizeImageAtPath( string filePath, float width, float height )` http://prime31.com/docs#iosEtc (sorry for shilling for someone else). So the hirez screenshot could be scaled to something that could be loaded as a texture for showing the user, and then the hirez original could be uploaded. I did this in a Unity app that manipulated photos, so it could work. (May require some ObjC coding from you)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To explain your own answer: This is not objective-C code, but plain old C, using the Mach APIs in order to obtain statistics from the kernel. Mach APIs are low level APIs exported by XNU, which is a hybrid kernel composed of the top layer (which exports BSD APIs, like the usual system calls we know and love from UN*X), and the bottom layer- which is Mach.
The code uses the Mach "host" abstraction which (among other things) provides statistics about OS level utilization of resources.

Specifically, here's a full annotation:

```
#import <mach/mach.h>       // Required for generic Mach typedefs, like the mach_port_t
#import <mach/mach_host.h>  // Required for the host abstraction APIs.

extern "C" // C, rather than objective-c
{

    const int HWUtils_getFreeMemory()
    {
        mach_port_t host_port;             
        mach_msg_type_number_t host_size;
        vm_size_t pagesize;

        // First, get a reference to the host port. Any task can do that, and this
        // requires no privileges
        host_port = mach_host_self();
        host_size = sizeof(vm_statistics_data_t) / sizeof(integer_t);

        // Get host page size - usually 4K
        host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize);

        vm_statistics_data_t vm_stat;

        // Call host_statistics, requesting VM information. 

        if (host_statistics(host_port,  // As obtained from mach_host_self()
             HOST_VM_INFO,              // Flavor - many more in <mach/host_info.h>(host_info_t)&vm_stat,                  // OUT - this will be populated
             &host_size)                // in/out - sizeof(vm_stat). 
              != KERN_SUCCESS)         
            NSLog(@"Failed to fetch vm statistics"); // log error

        /* Stats in bytes */
        // Calculating total and used just to show all available functionality

        // This part is basic math. Counts are all in pages, so multiply by pagesize
        // Memory used is sum of active pages, (resident, used)
        //                       inactive,      (resident, but not recently used)
        //                   and wired (locked in memory, e.g. kernel)

        natural_t mem_used = (vm_stat.active_count +
                              vm_stat.inactive_count +
                              vm_stat.wire_count) * pagesize;
        natural_t mem_free = vm_stat.free_count * pagesize;
        natural_t mem_total = mem_used + mem_free;
        NSLog(@"used: %u free: %u total: %u", mem_used, mem_free, mem_total);


        return (int) mem_free;
    }
```

Comment: Does this take in account memory used by gpu?

Answer (score 4):

So, with help of some objective-c gurus I've been able to find code snippet that is doing what I wanted. I must warn you that I don't understand how exactly this Obj-C code does what it does, and that it is considered a 'hack'; however, it turned out to be the best solution to my problem.

In plugin .mm file:

```
#import <mach/mach.h>
#import <mach/mach_host.h>

extern "C"
{

    const int HWUtils_getFreeMemory()
    {
        mach_port_t host_port;
        mach_msg_type_number_t host_size;
        vm_size_t pagesize;

        host_port = mach_host_self();
        host_size = sizeof(vm_statistics_data_t) / sizeof(integer_t);
        host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize);

        vm_statistics_data_t vm_stat;

        if (host_statistics(host_port, HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vm_stat, &host_size) != KERN_SUCCESS)
            NSLog(@"Failed to fetch vm statistics");

        /* Stats in bytes */
        // Calculating total and used just to show all available functionality
        natural_t mem_used = (vm_stat.active_count +
                              vm_stat.inactive_count +
                              vm_stat.wire_count) * pagesize;
        natural_t mem_free = vm_stat.free_count * pagesize;
        natural_t mem_total = mem_used + mem_free;
        NSLog(@"used: %u free: %u total: %u", mem_used, mem_free, mem_total);

        return (int) mem_free;
    }

}
```

In my hardware utility file:

```
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    static extern int HWUtils_getFreeMemory();

#if UNITY_IPHONE && !UNITY_EDITOR
    public static int GetFreeMemory()
    {
        return HWUtils_getFreeMemory();
    }
#endif
```

Comment: For some strange reason, it still seems to me that asking people for help and then accepting my own answer is somewhat rude, so I would very gladly welcome criticism to this and would rather accept someone else's answer if it was more correct or detailed.

Comment: Could you provide some logs from this function? Seems that it obtains device's memory usage, not application's. I'm interested in "used: %u free: %u total: %u" log. If this call actually returns app's free memory - would be great to use it for me too)

Comment: It does, in fact, provides the device's memory usage; I'm just deducting that if the app will try to allocate more memory that the devices has, it will be forced to quit. So far it works precisely: the app without this check would be closed exactly when this check would show that the amount of memory that the app wants is less then free memory on the device.

Comment: Example log on iPhone4:

Sep 25 15:14:25 iPhone appName[942] <Warning>: used: 367292416 free: 13545472 total: 380837888
Sep 25 15:15:33 iPhone appName[942] <Warning>: used: 371781632 free: 11190272 total: 382971904

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting some GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error when reading pixels on Unity3D (iOS and Android.). After I have done many testing, the main problem is the my game's draw call is too high when I take the screenshot using ReadPixels method (around > 40 draw calls). Maybe you should investigate this factor too.

Comment: Although it's not the case for me, it's a great advice nevertheless, thanks!